# SQL query that contains a function counting other Concurrent and Active tickets as new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I'd like to query a SQL dbo to get how many "tickets" were open(post-started and pre-resolved) within a 20 minute window of when the current rows "ticket" was created.

Goal Table (where 4 items were active from 8:50 to 9:10):

```
ID   CreateDate         ConcurrentItems
123  12/1/2016 09:00        4
```

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT   Ticket_ID as ID, Created_Date as CreateDate,
    Count( 
            WHERE
             WorkItemType = 'Work Request' AND
             IncidentStartTime <= (Created_Date minus 10 minutes) AND
             IncidentResolvedTime > (Created_Date plus 10 minutes)
     )as ConcurrentItems

FROM   CurrentView
```

Where the Created_Date in the COUNT would be same as in the SELECT

Comment: show sample result here.

Comment: hey reds had a sample up there as "Goal Table"

Comment: just give a clear sample data and expected result.

Comment: using count you need to group by in what column? If not then you will get the whole count of records according to your where condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest `outer apply`:

```
SELECT Ticket_ID as ID, Created_Date as CreateDate, x.ConcurrentItems
FROM CurrentView v OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as ConcurrentItems
      FROM CurrentView v2
      WHERE v2.WorkItemType = 'Work Request' AND
            v2.IncidentStartTime <= DATEADD(minute, -10, v.Created_Date) AND 
            v2.IncidentResolvedTime > DATEADD(minute, 10, Created_Date)
    ) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show the count for every CreatedDate with a condition:

```
select Created_Date, count(1) as ConcurrentItems from CurrentView
where WorkItemType = 'Work Request' AND
IncidentStartTime <= DATEADD(Minute, -10 CreateDate) AND
IncidentResolvedTime > DATEADD(Minute, +10 CreateDate) group by Created_Date
```

But this will show a count for every CreatedDate specifically.